# Getting a list of Urls and then finding specific text from all of them in Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

So I have this code that will give me the urls I need in a list format

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

offset = 0
links = []
with requests.Session() as session:
while True:
    r = session.get("http://rayleighev.deviantart.com/gallery/44021661/Reddit?offset=%d" % offset)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    new_links = soup.find_all("a", {'class' : "thumb"})

    # no more links - break the loop
    if not new_links:
        break

    # denotes the number of gallery pages gone through at one time (# of pages times 24 equals the number below)
    links.extend(new_links)
    print(len(links))
    offset += 24

    #denotes the number of gallery pages(# of pages times 24 equals the number below)
    if offset == 48:
        break

for link in links:
    print(link.get("href"))
```

After that I try to get different text from all of the urls, and all that text is in relatively the same place on each one. But, whenever I run the second half, below, I keep getting a chunk of html text and some errors, and I'm not sure of how to fix it or if there is any other, and preferably simpler, way to get the text from each url.

```
import urllib.request
import re

for link in links:
    url = print("%s" % link) 

headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()

paragraphs = re.findall(r'</a><br /><br />(.*?)</div>', str(respData))

if paragraphs != None:
    paragraphs = re.findall(r'<br /><br />(.*?)</span>', str(respData))

if paragraphs != None:
    paragraphs = re.findall(r'<br /><br />(.*?)</span></div>', str(respData))

for eachP in paragraphs:
    print(eachP)

title = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>', str(respData))
for eachT in title:
    print(eachT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
for link in links:
    url = print("%s" % link)
```

assigns None to url. Perhaps you mean:

```
for link in links:
    url = "%s" % link.get("href")
```

There's also no reason to use urllib to get the sites content, you can use requests as you did before by changing:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()
```

to

```
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
```

Now you can get the title and paragraph with just:

```
title = soup.find('div', {'class': 'dev-title-container'}).h1.text
paragraph = soup.find('div', {'class': 'text block'}).text
```

Comment: When I use the code you gave me it only returns the title and paragraph for the last url in the list. Is there a way for me to get the titles and paragraphs for all the urls in the list?

Comment: @Rayleighev is the code inside the 'links' for loop?

Comment: Yeah, when its ether in or out of 'links' I get the same result of only the text from the last url coming through.

Comment: @Reyleighev are you printing the text inside the loop because if you are it should work. If you're not but want to, you have to  append the title and paragraph to a list in the for loop

Comment: @ H. Lewroll Yup the print command is inside the 'link' loop and I get the text from the last url on the list and then the list of the urls themselves. I messed around with it some more and by changing the, if offset == number, to a higher number I can get more of the text but it starts going through the list starting randomly in the middle and then I get the same list of urls, but only they repeat again and again for the same number I set the , if offset == number,  to.

Comment: @Rayleighev [this](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/5983) seems to work for me

Comment: Yup, it works now thank you and thanks agan for the help.